# This file is within module ".", which is not included in your workspace

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

I have a golang project which includes windows-specific code. When working on this project from vscode running on macOS, I'm getting the following warning opening file `getFileCreationTime_windows.go`:

> This file is within module ".", which is not included in your workspace.
> To fix this problem, you can add a go.work file that uses this directory.
> See the documentation for more information on setting up your workspace:
> https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/workspace.md. go list

It's not clear to me what should I do with this warning. I'm not using multiple modules, it's a simple application project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Go language server does not support build tags very well. See the discussions in this issue: [x/tools/gopls: improve handling for build tags #29202](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202).

You can ignore this warning message.

If you need completions, diagnostics, etc for this file, you can choose one of the following approaches:

1. If you only need to edit files for other platforms occasionally, you can start VSCode like this:

   ```
   GOOS=windows code /path/to/the/project
   ```
2. If you are developing codes for other platforms most of the time and you don't want to specify `GOOS` every time, you can save it to the `.vscode/settings.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "go.toolsEnvVars": { "GOOS": "windows" }
   }
   ```